# Difference between RequestParameter and QueryParameter

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, cloudpage

I'm retrieving a URL parameter from a CloudPage. What is the difference between [RequestParameter()](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/microsite_and_landing_page_ampscript_functions/requestparameter/) and [QueryParameter()](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/microsite_and_landing_page_ampscript_functions/queryparameter/)? They appear to do the same thing. Are there scenarios where you would need to use one over the other?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "query" of a page's life cycle is the stuff after the "?" character in a URL, while a request parameter is one placed in the body of the request (a "form post"). Let's look at an example of what a browser might send to a server:

```
POST /path/to/file?The-Query-String=Here&Query-Values=Are-In-The-Url HTTP/1.1
Host: myhost.com
Content-Length: 52
Content-Type: x-www-form-urlencoded

Request-Body=Here&Request-Values=Are-In-The-Form-Post
```

However, in the documentation for the RequestParameter, it explicitly states that it can return query parameters (the part in the URL), *and* values in the form's post.

You can use QueryParameter to ignore form values, while you'd want to use RequestParameter if you need to read the values from a form post. RequestParameter may return more values than QueryParameter, especially if the request is a form post.

Comment: I built a simple HTML submit form post, and both functions (QueryParameter and RequestParameter) can capture element id values. Is it another form post you was mentioning?

Comment: @duyduc27 it depends on how the form submit action is set up. In general, I would suggest using RequestParameter to read form post values.